# large mounts of emails being sent from server unable to identify

Tags: ssh, email

I have a bit of a dilemma, I'm not sure how to solve. I have found coming from a folder on my server massive amounts of emails, but when I look in the folder, no single php file is sending that amount of emails.

here is what I have done so far logged onto SSH

run command

```
  grep cwd /var/log/exim_mainlog | grep -v /var/spool | awk -F"cwd=" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I then run command

```
  ls -lahtr /root/to/folder
```

but it didn't show any script that was sending high amounts of emails, when I say high the last time a looked today it was set at 135,000.

any suggestions about how to move forward?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
netstat -tnp
```

to find the process PID that is talking to port 25 on remote servers.

Use ps and look at /proc/PID/cmd and /proc/PID/exe .

Check the server logs (eg apache error log) for strange output like that of a wget command.

Likely a PHP or other CGI has a security hole that needs to be fixed.  If this is a shared server possibly someone has a weak FTP password.

Update: I forgot to mention that in Linux a process can be started and then the file deleted from the directory so you might not see the file anymore.  To copy the executable out of memory use

```
cp /proc/PID/exe foo.exe
```

Then you can examine the file.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your help, i'll give this a go and let you know what i f ind.

Comment: hi, i have just checked but there is no PID folder n /proc

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that someone is using your `SMTP` server to send mails because its policies allows it.

Do you have `dovecot` or `courier` services running on your server?

Comment: hi, thank you for your help, i can see dovecot running,  but if its installed where would i find courier woudl it be in       /etc/ini.d/

Comment: @user2513528 The binary package name on debian distributions is: `dovecot-core` and have files in `/etc/default` `/etc/dovecot` `/etc/init.d` `/etc/pam.d` `/usr/bin` `/usr/lib` `/usr/sbin` `/usr/share` you can also type: `nc localhost 25` and see what happens. If a `SMTP Server` is running you will see something like: `220-localhost ESMTP Exim 4.84 #2 Sat, 06 Feb 2016 12:29:45 -0700`

Comment: hi thank  you , but for some reason my nc command is not working

Comment: @user2513528 you can also try with `netcat localhost 25`, if the connection is refused, it means that no server is listening on port 25....

Comment: hi, i have tried that aswell, i get response  -bash: netcat: command not found

Comment: @user2513528 if you have the `netstat` command and `grep`, you can try `netstat -anp | grep :25` to see if the port 25 (`SMTP`) is listening and the `PID` of that process

Comment: hi thank you  so what i see is   `tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:25    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN    1724/exim`     and      `tcp    0     0:::25         :::*    LISTEN     1724/exim`

Comment: @user2513528 It is probable that some spammer is abusing of your `exim4 smtp server` to relay mails. To know if your server is vulnerable, you can enter your server IP address (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and the `TCP port 25` I am understanding, that you have a `VPS` with dedicated IP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35427/discussion-between-user2513528-and-ncomputers-org).